# How to leverage event loop in JavaScript and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, event-loop

<strike>Is the concept of event loop general or specific to languages?</strike> I am looking for detailed explanations with examples to clearly understand the following:

<strike>1. how it works?</strike>

1. How/when should/can I leverage event loop in **JavaScript**?
2. Any changes introduced in **ECMAScript-6/2015** regarding event loop?

<strike>Update:
There's no dearth of answers to this but I'm looking for an easy to understand definition with examples.</strike>

### Addendum:

Consider the following code:

```
var list = readHugeList();

var nextListItem = function() {
    var item = list.pop();

    if (item) {
        // process the list item...
        setTimeout( nextListItem, 0);
    }
};
```

Is it correct to assume setTimeout() here uses the event loop to prevent stackoverflow? I read an explanation for this code that:

> The stack overflow is eliminated because the **event loop** handles the recursion, not the call stack.

### Update 2

The full explanation given for the setTimeout() in the code above is as follows:

> The stack overflow is eliminated because the **event loop** handles the recursion, not the call stack. When **nextListItem** runs, if item is not null, the timeout function (nextListItem) is pushed to the **event queue** and the function exits, thereby leaving the call stack clear. When the event queue runs its **timed-out event**, the next item is processed and a timer is set to again invoke nextListItem. Accordingly, the method is processed from start to finish without a direct recursive call, so the **call stack remains clear**, regardless of the number of iterations.

The contradiction in explanations, aforementioned and in the answers here, is making it all the more difficult to understand.

Comment: AFAIK ecmascript doesn't define event loop at all. So there is not such thing as JavaScript event loop. It is implementation (e.g. nodejs) dependent.

Comment: Event loops are general across platforms. The implementation details will differ slightly, but the concept won't. You are constantly "leveraging" the event loop by the mere fact that you can respond to events in Javascript, like a button click, an incoming network request, or a finished AJAX request.

Comment: What level of answer do you want? How it works can be everything from "here's and example of how to use `setTimeout`" to "this is what happens in C"

Comment: @freakish: It does, as of the ES2015 spec. It calls it a "job queue."

Comment: @slebetman A simple js example would do. Some short explanation in simpler words how it works in nodej.js would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you want a simple js example there are already lots of duplicates. No reason not to close this.

Comment: Here are 3 answers I've written, at different levels of detail, describing the event loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799316/was-the-event-loop-model-used-in-web-browsers-to-control-interaction-between-dom/29799654#29799654, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616477/does-javascript-process-using-an-elastic-racetrack-algorithm/19620041#19620041, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883525/i-know-that-callback-function-runs-asynchronously-but-why/29885509#29885509

Answer (score 4):

> Is the concept of event loop general or specific to languages?

At its highest level, general. But different environments will implement the details so differently that really you need environment-specific information to know what's going on.

> how it works?

All the gory details are in the specification, chiefly in the section called [Jobs and Job Queues](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-jobs-and-job-queues).

There are a couple of keys aspects:

1. There is a *queue* of *jobs* (the JavaScript spec's term) or "tasks" (as the HTML spec calls them) waiting to be run by the JavaScript engine. When the engine finishes a job, it's put to work on the next job/task in the queue, if any.
2. Once a job is *started*, it keeps running until it's done; no other jobs can interrupt it. This is called *run-to-completion* and is very important to the definition of how JavaScript works.
3. The job queue is processed in order.

So consider this code:

```
console.log("one");
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("two");
}, 1000);
```

If you run that code (via NodeJS or a browser), here's what happens (omitting some irrelevant details):

1. At the beginning, the queue is empty and the JavaScript engine is idle
2. The environment (NodeJS, the browser) queues a job to run the script
3. The JavaScript engine picks up the job and runs the script:

   - It outputs "one"
   - It sets a timer for the anonymous function we gave to `setTimeout`
   - The job ends
4. At some point, the timer mechanism in the environment determines that it's time to call the callback, so it queues a job to call it
5. The JavaScript engine picks up that job from the queue and runs the function

   - It outputs "two"
   - The job ends

Now consider this code:

```
console.log(Date.now(), "one");
setTimeout(function first() {
    console.log(Date.now(), "two");
}, 500);
setTimeout(function second() {
    var end = Date.now() + 1000;
    while (end > Date.now()) {
        // Busy-wait (normally this is a Bad Thing™, I'm using it here
        // to simulate actual work that takes significant time
    }
}, 100);
```

As you can see, it schedules a timed callback at 500ms and then another at 100ms. But the code in the callback at 100ms will take at least 1000ms to run. What happens?

1. The environment queues a job to run the script
2. The JS engine picks that job up

   - Outputs the time value and "one", say `1470727293584 one`
   - Sets a timed callback to the function `first` for 500ms in the future
   - Sets a timed callback to the function `second` for 100ms in the future
   - The job ends
3. About 100ms later, the environment queues a job to run `second`
4. The JavaScript engine picks up the job and runs the function

   - It starts doing work (okay, so really it's just busy waiting)
5. About 400ms later (500ms from the time the timer was set), the environment queues a job to call `first`; since the JavaScript engine is busy with the previous job, the job sits in the queue
6. Meanwhile, the JavaScript engine is still working on the job calling `first`:

   - Eventually the work being done by the JavaScript engine from #3 is done
   - The job finishes
7. The JavaScript engine picks up the next job from the queue and runs the call to `second`

   - It outputs the time value and "two", say `1470727294687 two`
   - The job ends

Note that the *environment* did something while JavaScript was busy; it queued a job to be done.

The fact that the *environment* can do things while the JavaScript engine is busy is very important.

(It's worth noting that when queuing jobs, some environments may not necessarily add the job at the *end* of the queue; in some browsers, for instance, "the queue" is actually more than one queue with slightly different priorities...)

> how/when should/can I leverage it?

It's not so much *leveraging* it as knowing it's there. It's also important to note that while *JavaScript* has run-to-completion semantics, the environment in which it's running may be doing other things at the same time, even while the JavaScript code is running.

> any changes introduced in ECMAScript-6/2015 regarding event loop?

Not really, although it's defined much more completely in the spec than previously. Probably the closest thing to a *change* is in relation to promises: The callback you schedule with `then` or `catch` will *always* be queued as a job, it will never be run synchronously. That's the first time the JavaScript specification has defined something that happens asynchronously (ajax and timers are not part of the JavaScript spec).

---

Below, you've asked:

> Consider this code:
>
> ```
> var list = readHugeList();
> var nextListItem = function() {
>     var item = list.pop();
>     if (item) {
>         // process the list item...
>         setTimeout(nextListItem, 0);
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> Is it correct to assume setTimeout() here uses the event loop to prevent stackoverflow?

(I assume there's a `nextListItem();` call immediately after that.)

No, but it's doing something else important. The non-`setTimeout` version of that would look something like this:<sup>1</sup>

```
var list = readHugeList();
while (list.length) {
    var item = list.pop();
    // process the list item...
}
```

That's a simple loop, there's no potential for stack overflow.

What it's doing is working cooperatively with the event loop, avoiding having a really long-running job that would tie up the JavaScript engine, preventing it processing any other jobs (such as I/O completions, clicks, or other events). So it's breaking the work up into small jobs by processing the items one at a time, helping ensure that the overall job queue keeps getting processed. That means it takes a lot longer to process the list, but doesn't block other things while doing so.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's true that the non-`setTimeout` version of that code *could* look like this:

```
var list = readHugeList();
var nextListItem = function() {
    var item = list.pop();
    if (item) {
        // process the list item...
        // then recurse
        nextListItem();
    }
};
nextListItem();
```

...and in that case, there's potential for stack overflow, but it would be a very odd way to write that code.

Comment: That's a very detailed answer. Thank you. If I have a recursive function to access a very large list, would a settimeout() function inside the recursive function to prevent stackoverflow be termed as leveraging the event loop?

Comment: @steady_daddy: I'm not sure how you could use a `setTimeout` within a truly recursive function, since the stack has to unwind before the job can end, meaning the function has terminated, before the timer callback can run. But using `setTimeout` to schedule something to happen after the current job finishes is a common technique, and definitely leverages the queue. Suppose you do something you know will immediately queue an event callback. You can use `setTimeout` with a value of 0 to schedule some code ro run *after* that event callback, knowing that the queue is processed in order.

Comment: Consider this code: var list = readHugeList();

var nextListItem = function() {
    var item = list.pop();

    if (item) {
        // process the list item...
        setTimeout( nextListItem, 0);
    }
};  Is it correct to assume setTimeout() here uses the event loop to prevent stackoverflow?

Comment: @steady_daddy: No (not unless that code were written a bit oddly to start with), but it's doing something else important. I've added to the end of the answer.

Comment: I beg your indulgence, sir. Please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: @steady_daddy: This is turning into a bit of a moving target, which SO questions are meant not to be. Re the update: It's impossible to understand that without seeing what code they're comparing to (e.g., what is *their* version of the code *without* `setTimeout`) since, again, any reasonable way of writing the code without `setTimeout` will not involve recursion. It's possible the explanation you've quoted is just plain wrong.

Comment: If you replace setTimeout() line with nextListItem(), it is a recursive function which could cause stackoverflow for large list items. Introducing the timeout was their way to avoid the same. The explanation talked about event loop and that is how, in your words, this became a moving target. I stretched it thus far just to understand the concept of event loop in the context of the code.

Comment: @steady_daddy: I covered that at the end of the answer, with my speculative version of it using recursion.