# Can I trust setTimeout(fn, 0), or should I use an alternative?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, aurelia

While a lot of questions and answers tell me WHY and WHAT the `setTimeout(0)` is for, I cannot find a very good alternative for it.

**My problem**

I have a click handler, wich executes a function that signals another class to update its status.

That click handler is on the parent element.

I have a checkbox inside that element, wich gets checked or unchecked.

Because the click handler is on the parent element, that gets called first. But I need my checkbox to change status before the signal is send.

So I use `setTimeout(0)` to prevent the signal to be send before the checkbox is checked.

**HTML**

```html
<div click.delegate="update()">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input checked.bind="group.validated" type="checkbox"> Visibility
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
update(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.signaler.signal('refresh-groups');
    }, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Basically, what is happening, is that the `return true;` is executed before the `this.signaler.signal` function. That way, the checkbox gets checked *before* the signal is send. *Note this won't happen in regular `onclick` methods where the checkbox status is updated first, but this is the way the `Aurelia` framework behaves.*

I don't like the feeling that I create here. A timeout of 0 seconds means that the function is at the end of the callstack, nothing more. If anything would happen to my `return true;` statement causing it to wait 0.1 second, I face the same problem.

Is there any alternative that is more trustworthy? Simply using a `Promise` doesnt seem to do the trick here.

Comment: For those who might not have known about `setTimeout(fn, 0)` (myself included), see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

Comment: *"A timeout of 0 seconds means that the function is at the end of the callstack, nothing more. If anything would happen to my return true; statement causing it to wait 0.1 second, I face the same problem."* What do you mean, "you face the same problem"? Your `setTimeout` callback **will not** execute before your `update` method returns, no matter how long that takes.

Comment: @MysterX that would have been a great alternative, but there is no function called. The only thing I wait for is the checkbox getting checked, so I cant run `window.clearImmediate`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I did not know that. I figured JS would simply continue execution, only the order was changed by the `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Randy: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38844376/157247) useful re the job queue used by JavaScript.

Comment: So why are you not just listening for the change event?

Comment: @epascarello Because the actual change event on the checkbox does not update my variable immediately, but that *is* what I am waiting for. It is the `checked.bind` that forces me into this `setTimeout()`

Comment: Btw, the underlying mechanism of `setTimeout` prepends the callback to the next iteration of the event loop. If you want it to be appended to the current iteration, use the `MutationObserver` API.

Comment: Instead of using `MutationObserver` directly, you could use `aurelia-task-queue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary issue is you're using the `click` event which fires *before* the input element's value changes. Use the `change` event instead.

https://gist.run/?id=863282464762b54c8cf67de541bac4d3

Comment: Nice!!! Let me ask you a question Danyow. Would my answer also work in this case?

Comment: @FabioLuz - It definitely would work. I try to avoid using the TaskQueue and Signaler where possible- there's usually a more natural way of doing things.

Comment: yeah, your solution is much more simpler (even though someone voted it down WTF?). I was trying to follow OP's logic, it's good to know that it would work (and it also was voted down ¯\_(ツ)_/¯). Thank you!

Comment: This is epic, I never knew that you could hang a `change` handler on a regular element.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `this.signaler.signal()` as Task. For instance:

```
import {BindingSignaler} from 'aurelia-templating-resources';
import { TaskQueue } from 'aurelia-task-queue';

export class App {

  static inject() { return [BindingSignaler, TaskQueue]; }

  constructor(signaler, taskQueue) {
    this.signaler = signaler;
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
  }

  update(){
    this.taskQueue.queueTask(() => {
        this.signaler.signal('refresh-groups');
    });

    return true;
  }
}
```

See this example https://gist.run/?id=88500143701dab0b0697b17a211af3a7